# Reusable search when using forkJoin in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In every module that an AJAX request is made, a loader image is used to block the content until the request(s) have completed. Most modules perform one to three requests, so our go to solution was to use multiple callbacks. When I came across a component that makes eight separate calls, I immediately set out to find a better way and discovered `forkJoin`. Using `forkJoin` requires us to change how we're handling the requests. This is a good sample of how our code would change:

Before:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.showLoader();
    this.getUsers(() => {
        this.onSearch();
    });
}

getUsers(callback: Function) {
    return this.userService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.users = data;
                callback();
            }
            error => this.showError('Error getting Users', error)
        );
}

onSearch(view?: string) {
    this.showLoader();
    // parameter related logic

    return this.expenseService.search(view)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results = data;
                this.hideLoader();
            }
            error => this.showError('Error getting Expenses', error)
        );
}
```

After:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.showLoader();

    forkJoin([
        this.getUsers(),
        this.onSearch()
    ]).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.users = data[0];
            this.results = data[1];
            this.hideLoader();
        },
        error => this.showError('Unexpected Error', error)
    );
}

getUsers() {
    return this.userService.getUsers();
}

onSearch(view?: string) {
    // parameter related logic
    return this.expenseService.search(view);
}
```

I'm satisfied with these changes for the most part; the generic error handling frustrates me since I am not able to customize the error within TypeScript for the call that failed and will have to tweak my API. The real issue is with reusable methods, like `onSearch()`, which I want to call when the module is loading and when a search field is changed. The only solution I can come up with is to call `onSearch()` after the `forkJoin` requests have completed:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.showLoader();

    forkJoin([
        this.getUsers()
    ]).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.users = data[0];
            this.onSearch();
        },
        error => this.showError('Unexpected Error', error)
    );
}

getUsers() {
    return this.userService.getUsers();
}

onSearch(view?: string) {
    this.showLoader();
    // parameter related logic
    this.expenseService.search(view)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results = data;
                this.hideLoader();
            }
            error => this.showError('Error getting Expenses', error)
        );
}
```

A slight variation would be to return `this.expenseService.search()` in separate method and both `forkJoin` and `onSearch()` could use it, but it feels unnecessary.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.showLoader();

    forkJoin([
        this.getUsers(),
        this.getExpenses()
    ]).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.users = data[0];
            this.results = data[1];
            this.hideLoader();
        },
        error => this.showError('Unexpected Error', error)
    );
}

getUsers() {
    return this.userService.getUsers();
}

getExpenses(view?: string) {
    // parameter related logic
    return this.expenseService.search(view);
}

onSearch(view: string) {
    this.showLoader();
    this.getExpenses(view)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results = data;
                this.hideLoader();
            }
            error => this.showError('Error getting Expenses', error)
        );
}
```

I am still relatively new to Angular, so maybe there is something about `forkJoin` or subscriptions that I am not aware of that I can leverage. Is there a better way than either of the two options I have listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways that you could do this. One would be to extract out the `forkJoin` part from `ngOnInit` and pass in the actual methods you want to use. For example:

```
getData(methods) {
  this.showLoader();
  forkJoin(methods).subscribe({
    error: error => this.showError('Unexpected Error', error),
    complete: () => this.hideLoader(),
  });
}
```

Then you can use this in `ngOnInit`:

```
// arrow function used to keep lexical binding
this.getData([() => this.getUsers(), () => this.getExpenses()]);
```

...and `onSearch`:

```
this.getData([() => this.getExpenses(view)]);
```

In order to update the results, you can update your retrieval function observables. For example:

```
getUsers() {
    return this.userService.getUsers().pipe(map(data => this.users = data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an alternative option. I like it and I don't, but nothing so far has stood out as something I am completely sold on.

Comment: To be honest, the best solution in this case would be to change the APIs so you only have to do one call at a time for all the information you need (GraphQL, for example)